# How to inform and update a client when a new record inserted in mysql database using node js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

Cant update list of records in client using mysql node js and socket.io

Hi Everybody , i want to update client when new record is inserted in mysql database , im using node js and socket.io .

What can i do for this problem , im new to node js and socket forgive me if my code is too confusing .
i searched alot but not found anything  .
any suggestions will be helpfull .
here is my server.js file :

```
    var mysql = require('mysql') ;
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000) ;

var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    database:'mygame'
});

db.connect(function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Connected Successfully To The Database");
});

// Here We Need List Of Competitions To Emit To All Clients 

var Competitions = [] ;
var isInitCompetitions = false ;
var socketCount = 0 ;

//
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    Competitions = [];
    db.query("SELECT * FROM comps WHERE compstatus='1'").on(
        'result',function(data) {

            Competitions.push(data) ;
        }
    ).on(
        'end',function(){
            socket.emit('all competitions',Competitions);
        }
    ) ;
    socketCount++ ;
    io.sockets.emit('Another User Is Connected : ' ,socketCount);
    console.log('One User Is Connected');
    socket.on('disconnect',function() {
        io.sockets.emit('One User Left : ' ,socketCount);
    });

    function checkNewCompetitions() {
        socket.on('newcomp',function(){
            db.query("SELECT * FROM comps WHERE compstatus='1'").on(
                'result',function(data) {
                    Competitions = [];
                    Competitions.push(data) ; 
                }
            ).on(
                'end',function(){
                    socket.emit('all competitions',Competitions);
                    console.log('Number Of Competitions in Flow : ' , Competitions.length) ;
                }
            ) ;
        });
    }
    setInterval(checkNewCompetitions,3000);



});
```

and here is my index.html file :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
        socket.on('all competitions',function(data) {
           var html = ''  ;
           for(var i = 0 ;i < data.length; i++){
               html += '<li>'+data[i].id + '</li>';
           }
           $('#competitions').html(html);
        });
        socket.on('newcomp',function(data) {
           var html = ''  ;
           for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
               const element = data[index];
               html += '<li>' + data[index].id + '</li>';
           }
           $('#competitions').html(html);
        });
    });
</script>
<p>This is List Of Competitions</p>
<ul id="competitions"></ul>
```

i run this code but im getting this erro :

```
(node:8628) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 newcomp listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

What can i do for this problem , thanks to this greate community .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every 3 seconds you add an new Event Listener so the MaxListenersExceededWarning occurs. Call checkNewCompitions every 3 seconds is ok. If there is a new comp you have to emit a newComp event with socket.emit('newcomp')

```
    socketCount++ ;
    io.sockets.emit('Another User Is Connected : ' ,socketCount);
    console.log('One User Is Connected');
    socket.on('disconnect',function() {
        io.sockets.emit('One User Left : ' ,socketCount);
    });

    function checkNewCompetitions() {
/// Every 3 seconds you check the database for new comps
            db.query("SELECT * FROM comps WHERE compstatus='1'").on(
                'result',function(data) {
                    Competitions = [];
                    Competitions.push(data) ; 
                }
            ).on(
                'end',function(){

// here you have to call socket.emit('newComp') 
// so the client gets the event a new comp is inserted in database. 

                    socket.emit('all competitions',Competitions);
                    console.log('Number Of Competitions in Flow : ' , Competitions.length) ;
                }
            ) ;

    }
    setInterval(checkNewCompetitions,3000);

});
```

And i cannot find where you emit the 'newcomp' event. So the socket.on('newcomp'..) never get called

Comment: So How can i inform client of new records in database ? @camen6ert

Comment: First you need a insert statement so a new record in the database is generated. And if your insert statement is successfull you call socket.emit('newcomp'). This will emit a new event and on all connected clients the code socket.on('newcomp', function(data) {....} will be called

Comment: the problem is that i have an admin panel with php , and the admin every time he wants can insert or update the databse , i want to handle these in node js server file

Comment: A know i now what you want with setInterval. Wait a second I edit the answer